# How can rank set of concepts depend on TF-IDF

Tags: information-retrieval, tf-idf

I  have  concept (cat)  occur in 3 documents d  of 5 documents 
for example

cat d1  3 times occur

cat d2  4 times occur

cat d5  2 times occur

I  know tf/idf  provide the weight of cat in d1  d2  and d5 
but I wonder how can I get the weight of cat in general I mean the weight of cat based of 5 documents.

Comment: If I got it right, the idea behind IDF should already provide what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By defiition the `tf/idf` is a measure that gives a weight for each word in a given document. Thus, you could calculte the `tf/idf` weight for the concept `cat` in `d5` for instance as follows: The `tf` is simply  `tf(cat,d5)=2`. The `idf` part is equal to the logarithm of the number of document in the collection divided by the number of documents in which this word is mentioned. In our case, `idf(cat,D)= log(5/3)`. Next, the  `tf/idf` weight could be culculated as `tf/idf(cat,d5)=2* log(5/3)`.

As it can be seen, `tf/idf` works on a single doument. If your goal is to find a weight for a term across all documents (or some category within your collection), you may need to look at different meathod (Lanuguage Modelling [LM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_model) for instance).